# CSS3 Animation pendulum effect

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want pendulum effect with pure CSS but it's not smooth.

Here is what I want, but with pure CSS. http://www.webdevdoor.com/demos/html5-pendulum-demo/

But I prefer more looked like natural speed variation according to it's position.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/b4kbubwb/)

```css
.bellImg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="bellImg" src="img/bell.png">
```

Comment: I want pendulum to go to 0 to 20 and to -20 smoothly. So, I added all these. I have tried with only 20, 0 and -20 but it's also not smooth.

Comment: Hate to play devil's advocate, but why are you so adverse to using a library? GSAP is super capable, and it would cut down on that awful CSS bloat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

- The [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) is specified as `ease-in-out`. This indicates that the animation starts and end slowly but has more speed in between. For a graceful and equal move, this should be set to `linear`.

  > This is what [MDN says about ease-in-out timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function):
  >
  > This keyword represents the timing function cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.0, 0.58, 1.0). With this timing function, the animation starts slowly, accelerates then slows down when approaching its final state. At the beginning, it behaves similarly to the ease-in function; at the end, it is similar to the ease-out function.
- There is no value called `linear` for [`animation-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction).
- The splits are not equal. That is, for some 10% gap it is rotating by 10 degree whereas for others it is rotating only by 5 degree. Make the splits equal.

The below snippet with all corrections done produces a smooth animation.

```css
.bellImg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  /* or make your custom easing */
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="bellImg" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/bell_sound_notification_remind_reminder_ring_ringing_schedule-48.png">
```

---

<strike>Setting the animation's speed to depend on the position (that is, slow down as it reaches the extremes and quicken up in the middle) is impossible to achieve with pure CSS (even if we add extra elements)</strike>.

For setting the animation's speed depending on its position, one option would be to do the following:

- Add the image into a container element. Animate it such that it rotates from 20deg to -40deg.
- Make the animation on the parent start earlier than the child by 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of the animation duration of both. That is, reduce the delay on parent by `0.66s`. This is done to get the parent to offset initial rotation on the child. The difference is 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of animation duration because it is the time taken by parent to come to 0deg.
- Change the keyframes for the image's animation such that the rotation is from -20deg to 40deg.
- Set the `animation-direction` as `alternate` for both so that they go in forward direction for first iteration, in reverse for the next and so on.
- Set the `animation-timing-function` as `ease-in-out` so that it slows down as it approaches the extremes. The effect is more apparent when the animation duration is increased.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  /* right: 10px; commented for demo */
  top: 18px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  animation-name: rotate-container;
  animation-delay: 2.33s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.bellImg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(40deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-container {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <img class="bellImg" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/bell_sound_notification_remind_reminder_ring_ringing_schedule-48.png">
</div>
```

<sup>Prefix-free library is used in the snippet only to avoid browser prefixes.</sup>

Comment: I want more natural like speed increases and decreases according to it's position.

Comment: it should me quick at returning centre (0 deg) and slow at maximum deg (reaching 20deg/-20deg)

Comment: @MadanBhandari: I think then you'd need the animation start at either extreme and then use `ease-in-out` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4kbubwb/5/).

Comment: Or take a look at http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/ and create your own easing option.

Answer (score 4):

The equation involved in the movement of a pendulum is a sinusoidal movement.

You can get this movement with the following animation

```css
.base {
  height: 600px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: base 10s infinite linear;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transform: translateX(588px);
}

@keyframes base {
  from {transform: translateX(77px);}
  to {transform: translateX(760px);}
}

.element {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: element 10s infinite;
  transform: translateY(553px);
}

@keyframes element {
  from {transform: translateY(294px); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  25% {transform: translateY(36px); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  50% {transform: translateY(294px); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  75% {transform: translateY(553px); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  to {transform: translateY(294px);}
}

.ref {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx4bR.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="element">
</div>
</div>
<div class="ref"></div>
```

I had to use some hand-worked values to adjust for the background-image, but the key idea is in the timing functions.

If the preset function is not what you want, you can set a cubic bezier and adjust it as you want.

```css
.base {
  height: 600px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: base 10s infinite linear;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transform: translateX(588px);
}

@keyframes base {
  from {transform: translateX(77px);}
  to {transform: translateX(760px);}
}

.element {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: element 10s infinite;
  transform: translateY(553px);
}

@keyframes element {
  from {transform: translateY(294px); 
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 1);}
  25% {transform: translateY(36px); 
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.0, 0.9, 0.7);}
  50% {transform: translateY(294px); 
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 1);}
  75% {transform: translateY(553px); 
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.0, 0.9, 0.7);}
  to {transform: translateY(294px);}
}

.ref {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx4bR.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="element">
</div>
</div>
<div class="ref"></div>
```

This is the image used for reference

[image: grafic for reference]

And this would be the 2 timing functions applied to a pendulum

```css
.test {
  height: 400px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 100px;
  transform-origin: center top;
}

.anim1 {
   animation: oscil1 6s infinite; 
}

.anim2 {
   animation: oscil2 6s infinite; 
}


@keyframes oscil1 {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 1);}
  25% {transform: rotate(20deg); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.0, 0.9, 0.7);}
  50% {transform: rotate(0deg); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 1);}
  75% {transform: rotate(-20deg); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.0, 0.9, 0.7);}
  to {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

@keyframes oscil2 {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  25% {transform: rotate(20deg); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  50% {transform: rotate(0deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  75% {transform: rotate(-20deg); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  to {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="test anim1"></div>
<div class="test anim2"></div>
```

Comment: @Harry Thank you !  I have added another version with cubic bezier functions

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used CSS here, but since (it seems like) you just want to avoid *libraries*, I've implemented it in native JS. It uses the `Math.sin()` method to tween the values smoothly. As you can see, the effect is very smooth and requires very little code.

```js
var img = document.querySelector( '.bellImg' ),
    start = 0;
function sine(){
  img.style.transform = "rotate(" + 20 * Math.sin( start ) + "deg)";
  start += 0.05;
  setTimeout(sine, 1000/30)
}
setTimeout( sine, 3000 );
```

```css
.bellImg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 18px;
}
```

```html
<img class="bellImg" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/bell_sound_notification_remind_reminder_ring_ringing_schedule-48.png">
```

Hope this helps!